# Logic Apps: Data not parsed on the second query inside "foreach" loop

Tags: azure-logic-apps, kql, azure-sentinel

Hi Logic Apps Experts,

I'd like to check with you some of the foreach loop behaviors, and to check whether this is expected/ is there any workarounds for this.

[image: Logic Apps Illustration Examples]

So the steps with this logicapps is to "Run query and list results" search will do is searching SecurityIncident table. And foreach SecurityIncident record, find a corresponding SecurityAlert record in "Using IncidentId-Query Details of the Alert" step.

For the first query, the data is parsed properly and each fields can be used.
[image: Run query and list results]

However, after the second query I can only use 'Body' and 'value' in the steps. Which contains unparsed values.
[image: Using IncidentId - Query details of the alert]

Questions:

1. Is this behavior expected?
2. Is there a better way to ensure the second query is parsed?
3. Any other room of improvements advice are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The selection list affected by the required type/format of the input box in the action. So I think the behavior is expected.

If you want to get the parsed field from the query action, you can use expression. I'm not clear about the details of query result body, here I just provide a sample for your reference:

For example, if the query result shows like:

```
{
    "body": [
        {
            "TenantId": "111",
            "xxxx": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "TenantId": "222",
            "xxxx": "xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can use the expression `body('Run_query_and_list_results')[0]?['TenantId']` to get the value of first `TenantId`. In a word, use `[index]` to get array, use `?['key']` to get map.